# ASUS ROG II - Android Update

Tags: updates, rom-flashing

So, unfortunately I brought a Tencent Branded ASUS ROG II phone and paid a hefty amount for something ASUS calls unofficial

Consequences:

1. No Android Security Update
2. No Software Update since August 2019

Even after having the latest hardware and more RAM and Storage than my Laptop I am stuck at older software which is annoying.

I tried looking stuff to manually update to Android 10 as my device is not reciving any FOTA Updates but it says the Product ID, Fingerprint and the ROM should match i.e to WW ( Considering this is a Chinese phone flashed with global firmware / ROM) fortunately on my device it does but I still can't manually download ( Keep it in root) a FOTA Update and apply it(After Restart). It just fails, so I am skeptical to actually unlock the bootloader and do fancy stuff and end up bricking my device!

Is there a way I can completely get rid of the issue of manually upgrading the software ( by manually I mean connecting to a PC and flashing the latest FOTA)?

Some way I can just download the latest update keep it in root restart the device, it detects an update and does it automatically?

*Product : WW_l001D
Fingerprint : asus/WW_l001D/ASUS_l001_1:9/PKQ1.190414.001/16.0631.1908.12-0:user/release-keys*

Comment: Usually branded devices only allow applying OTA updates that are also using the same branded version. As far as I know, if you want to change the ROM the only way is to unlock the bootloader .

Comment: I am okay for doing it once and for all. Although the application I found for unlocking bootloader fails with network error